# Reading ADC value of sensor with PWM source

Tags: microcontroller, adc, pwm

As the topic mentioned, I have been working on getting ADC value of a sensor that is driven by a PWM source. I've come across a situation that when I am getting the ADC value with a rather long time interval, the ADC values I got fluctuated, while if I do it with a rather short period of time interval, the ADC values seemed to be stable, but the average value dropped.

It's should be quite abstract to describe it merely in words. I have done some testing and the following are the results

| Parameter | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Reference Resistance of Sensor: | 89.7k ohm |
| PWM voltage: | ~1.291 V |
| PWM Clock: | 80M |
| PWM counter: | 19000/25500 |

For the following graphs, X axis is time with 1 = 1 second, Y axis is ADC value.

[image]
[image]

| Time Interval | Average ADC value |
| --- | --- |
| 10ms | 502.4521964 |
| 25ms | 502.8478261 |
| 50ms | 529.2583732 |
| 100ms | 530.6435644 |
| 200ms | 529.5961538 |

I have done some more tests and found out that the average value started dropping if the time interval is smaller than 50ms, which also appears that the ADC values I get become more stable.

Could anyone tell me what situation I am in?

Comment: what do you mean by `situation` ... `what situation am I in?`  is not an electronics question

Comment: What type of sensor needs to be driven by PWM? Normally a sensor needs to be driven by a stable reference voltage, or a stable reference current source, or use ratiometric measurement to help cancel noise. If the PWM is not synchronous with the ADC sample rate, there's a very good chance the PWM itself is introducing measurement noise. Also, consider that SAR type of ADC (such as found on many microcontrollers) suffers noise when measuring high-impedance sources due to charge injection, which disrupts the measurement source right when sampling begins. Oscilloscope plots would confirm.

Comment: @MarkU Yes I know that sensor should normally be driven by stable voltage. The case is I am only in charge of the firmware but not the hardware, that means I must adapt to the situation that the sensor is driven by PWM voltage......

Comment: @jsotola the question should be: why would I get the ADC results differently when using different time interval to get the ADC value, and in what circumstances would a get a stable trend of ADC value, given that the PWM voltage source is a wave form, and apparently(?) not fast enough to act as a stable voltage source with respected to the sensor.

Comment: (1) Let me see if I understand your "situation". (2) Let us use the example case of a fast fluctuating temperature of a burning flame of a piece of wood. (3) So your ADC is converting the analog temperature of the flame into say, 12-bit digital values, at a sampling rate of say, up to 20k samples per second. (4) You are trying to take the moving average of, say, every 5 discrete samples. (5) Now you are using a PWM signal, for timing, say, (a) Low to pause (and let and ADC to complete), and (b) Low to High edge to start another ADC. Please let me know if I understand your situation correctly.

Comment: @tlfong01 When using stable 3.3V input to the sensor, the ADC value is stable. What the PWM tries to do is to work as a DC-DC converter, converting 3.3V to ~1.3V. As the PWM signal direclty input into the Vin of the sensor, basically the sensor goes on and off according to the PWM signal. The circuit is fix at this stage, I cannot add anything to the circuit. What I want ultimately is a stable ADC value, if possible. 10-bit digital value, 200 sample per second ultimately.

Comment: @Willai, Many thanks for your clarification. (6) So your goal is "a stable ADC value, if possible", not my wrong guess that you want a moving average. (7) Your spec of 10-bit resolution, 20 sps is indeed very humble. (8) You seems to want to use a "DC-DC converter", or a down DC level shifter. (9) So you have two jobs to do: (a) get the ADC value (10-bit, 20sps), this part is easy. (10) shift down proportionally from a DC voltage value in 3V3 range to 1.3V range.  Eg 3.3V to 1.3V, 1.65V to 0.65V, ... and so on. Please let me know If my guess of (10) is correct.

Comment: @tlfong01 (6) and (8) are correct. For (9a), should be 200sps. Merely taking the sample is what I have been doing. For (10), not proportionally, actually the PWM voltage, or the Vin of the sensor to be specific, should be within 0.9V~1.4V.

Comment: (9a) OK. 200sps. My apologies. Actually 20k sps is still low for many advanced ADC. (10) OK, not proportionally or linear, but perhaps more than simply shifting down, (11) Now some random ideas/suggestions, (11) For external or MCU built-in ADCs, it is common to have a "A ref" pin for you to input a DC reference voltage to determine the scale/output range of ADC results. (12) You can also have non-linear relationships between input x and output y values. So for linear relationship, you have y = kx, you can also have things like y = kx** + etc.

Comment: (13) You can also have "table lookup" methods with two columns, one column for input x, the other column for output y, saving any y = f(x) formula.  (14) I still don't understand why you need to use PWM, which is hardware oriented. Actually you can do the whole conversion using software. Just quick and dirty comments, my apologies for all the typos.

Comment: Did you consider that you have aliasing effects? Is the clock of the PWM coupled with the clock of your MCU? (It does not look like that.) -- Is the driving PWM signal available at some MCU pin? If so, you could use the raising edge as a synchronisation for the start of the conversion.